# Suppress fields in Crystal Reports based on a bit value from the DB

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, crystal-reports

I have set up a checkbox on the account creation page and linked to DB, if the user checks the box they are wanting certain items to show on their reports (PDF from CR). I have added the DB value to my schema (the bit value) and the other fields are present also.

How do I suppress the 3 items if the bit value is 0.

I've tried to suppress it with an IF/ELSE within CR but that's not working correctly.

Do I need to create a formula field and suppress the items from it?

Examples would be appreciated as I've tried everything I can think of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right click field and choose 'Format Field...'.  Select the Common tab.  Click the button to the right of the Suppress checkbox.  Enter the following text in the formula:

```
CurrentFieldValue=0
```

Repeat process with other fields or use the Format Painter button to do so.

Comment: PERFECT! I did this but CR kept popping an error: 'A string is required here.' I ignored the warning and now it suppresses the value when False. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you are populating a DataTable and passing that to CR, then you could ues a ForEach loop to go through the DataRows and massage the data there.

Better still, you could handle this in the stored procedure that is returning the data.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but the method above was quicker (for me) at least.